# loading a byte array as an application/pdf mimetype into a UIWebview

Tags: iphone

I was able to retrieve a pdf file from a web service as a byte array.

I want to load it into a UIWebView for iOS but when I try it using the following:

```
[wvLetter loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" 
                                     textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

The console tells me that:

> failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

I have seen this file, and it is indeed a pdf file, the retrieved size corresponds to the
original file.

What could be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the pdf is coming from a web service is it possible that byte array is being encoded in base64? That was the problem I was having. I found some objective-c code on [Cocoa with love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) that seemed to do the trick for me. All you have to do is pass through the NSString of the encoded byte array and it returns the equivalent NSData object back, ready to be loaded into the UIWebView. Hope that helps someone.